# Checking TimeSpan

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I have a method that queries active directory, and returns the value of the Last Password Reset to a local variable. I am trying to compare that value to the current date and time, and check if it's been less than 24 hours. I think I'm close, but can't seem to get this to work.

Thanks,
Jason

```
string passwordLastSet = string.Empty;
passwordLastSet = DateTime.FromFileTime((Int64)(result.Properties["PwdLastSet"][0])).ToString();  
public string lastReset(DateTime pwordLastReset)
{
    if (DateTime.Now.AddHours(24) <= passwordLastSet)
    {
        return "try again later";
    }
    else
    {
        return "all is good";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
 if (DateTime.Now.AddHours(24) <= passwordLastSet)
```

should be

```
   if (DateTime.Now <= passwordLastSet.AddHours(24))
```

Answer (score 7):

> I am trying to compare that value to the current date and time, and check if it's been less than 24 hours.

This code almost writes itself.

```
DateTime timeOfLastPasswordReset = // get time of last password reset
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan difference = now.Subtract(timeOfLastPasswordReset);
if(difference < TimeSpan.FromHours(24)) {
    // password was reset less than twenty-four hours ago
}
else {
    // password was reset no less than twenty-four hours ago
}
```

Note how the code reads exactly as you specified in English.

Answer (score 1):

How about (assuming I've read your intentions correctly):

```
// Does passwordLastSet, with 24 hours added to it, fall before or after DateTime.Now?
// If AFTER, then reject, if BEFORE, then accept
if (passwordLastSet.Add(new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0)) > DateTime.Now)
{
    // Password was last set within the last 24 hours
    return "try again later";
}
else
{
    return "all is good";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24) <= passwordLastSet` as you want to simulate that now is 24 hours in past, not in future

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string variable and a datetime variable, it is not possible to compare them

```
 DateTime passwordLastSet = DateTime.FromFileTime((Int64)(result.Properties["PwdLastSet"][0]));  
 public string lastReset(DateTime pwordLastReset)
 {
     if (DateTime.Now.AddHours(24) <= passwordLastSet)
     {
         return "try again later";
     }
     else
     {
         return "all is good";
     }
 }
```

Change your string  to DateTime if you want to compare it with current time.

Just use this

```
if (DateTime.Now <= passwordLastSet)
{
    return "try again later";
}
else
{
    return "all is good";
}
```

If you want to check it greater than 24 change both to TimeSpan and compare it.

Comment: if i change String passwordLastSet to DateTime password last set, I get a compile error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime' which I'm reading as I need to change the return type, or cast string to date time.

Comment: DateTime.FromFileTime((Int64)(result.Properties["PwdLastSet"][0])).ToString();   this line is causing error

Comment: change it DateTime.FromFileTime((Int64)(result.Properties["PwdLastSet"][0]));

Comment: I just realized the answer to my own comment, I just need to remove .ToString

Answer (score 0):

```
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(passwordLastSet).TotalHours < 24)
    Console.WriteLine("Try again");
else
    Console.WriteLine("all is good");
```

You can also use TotalDays < 1

Answer (score 0):

To be pedantic:

- You need to check for special cases before converting to DateTime - for example [pwdLastSet can be zero](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc220785(v=prot.10).aspx), so you should check this before attempting to convert.
- `pwdLastSet` is stored as UTC - so that converting to local time using `DateTime.FromFileTime` might return [an ambiguous time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397782.aspx).

  So it would be better to use `DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc` and compare with `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Depending on exactly what you want to achieve, you may also want to check the userAccountControl flags - something like the following (untested):

```
    [Flags]
    private enum AdsUserFlags
    {
        Script = 0x1,
        AccountDisabled = 0x2,
        HomeDirectoryRequired = 0x8,
        AccountLockedOut = 0x10,
        PasswordNotRequired = 0x20,
        PasswordCannotChange = 0x40,
        EncryptedTextPasswordAllowed = 0x80,
        TempDuplicateAccount = 0x100,
        NormalAccount = 0x200,
        InterDomainTrustAccount = 0x800,
        WorkstationTrustAccount = 0x1000,
        ServerTrustAccount = 0x2000,
        PasswordDoesNotExpire = 0x10000,
        MnsLogonAccount = 0x20000,
        SmartCardRequired = 0x40000,
        TrustedForDelegation = 0x80000,
        AccountNotDelegated = 0x100000,
        UseDesKeyOnly = 0x200000,
        DontRequirePreauth = 0x400000,
        PasswordExpired = 0x800000,
        TrustedToAuthenticateForDelegation = 0x1000000,
        NoAuthDataRequired = 0x2000000
    }

    ...
    AdsUserFlags userAccountControl = (AdsUserFlags)result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0];
    long lastReset = (long)result.Properties["PwdLastSet"][0];

    if (lastReset == 0L)
    {
        if ((userAccountControl & AdsUserFlags.PasswordDoesNotExpire) == 0)
        {
            // ... user must set password at next login
        }
        else
        {
            // ... presumably password has never been reset
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime lastResetUtc = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(lastReset);
        // ... etc - compare with DateTime.UtcNow
    }
```