# Need to compare pwdLastSet in Active Directory with current date and check if the password is about to expire. What would be the best way to do that?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, active-directory-group, directorysearcher

I have a requirement to compare pwdLastSet field from Active Directory with current date and if that date difference is a configurable number(fixed by client), we need to trigger email that password is about to expire. This date comparison also needs to be done with LastLoginTimeStamp in Active Directory to send emails. What would be the best way out to compare these fields as pwdLastSet is a long int and using it the DirectorySearcher filter to compare with current date will not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last password set date of a directory user in `DateTime` type by using nullable `LastPasswordSet` property of the `UserPrincipal` class from the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace.

If `User must change password at next logon` option is checked then `LastPasswordSet` property returns `null` value. Otherwise it returns the last date and time the password was set in type `DateTime`. Then you can compare dates with `DateTime.Compare` mathod.

```
using(PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, Username);
    //? - to mark DateTime type as nullable
    DateTime? pwdLastSet = (DateTime?)user.LastPasswordSet;
    int delta = 7;
    if (pwdLastSet != null)
    {
        if (DateTime.Compare((DateTime)pwdLastSet, DateTime.Now) < delta)
        {
            //send email
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

[MSDN: UserPrincipal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal_properties)
[MSDN: LastPasswordSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.lastpasswordset)

Comment: How-to check "User must change password at next logon" ? and unchecked ?

Answer (score 0):

To get a datetime from pwdLastSet:

```
SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne(); 
hacked = DateTime.FromFileTime((long)sr.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0]);
```

See [Casting ActiveDirectory pwdLastSet property without using ActiveDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592422/casting-activedirectory-pwdlastset-property-without-using-activeds) and [checking timespan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960728/checking-timespan)

Answer (score 0):

To see when pawword is going to expire

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} –Properties “DisplayName”, “msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed” |
    Select-Object -Property “Displayname”,@{Name=“ExpiryDate”;Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.“msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed”)}} | export-csv -path c:\paswsword-expiring.csv
```

See when password was last set

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -properties Displayname,PasswordLastSet | select displayname,passwordlastset |Format-List
```

set up email alert

http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Active_directory_password_expiration_notification